# Overriding Django REST Frameworks update method to save the nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF and I have been stuck with how to override update method in the serializers.py file.

Here are my models.

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    module_referred = models.ForeignKey(Course_Module, related_name="quiz")


class Course_Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The serializers that have been created for these models are as below:-

```
class QuizSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    questions = Quiz_QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ('url', 'quiz_name', 'module_referred')



class Course_ModuleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    quiz = QuizSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Course_Module
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'quiz')


    def create(self, validated_data):
        quiz_data = validated_data.pop('quiz')
        module = Course_Module.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for qd in quiz_data:
            Quiz.objects.create(module_referred = module, **qd)
        return module

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Somehow save instance with new quiz_data
        return instance
```

A typical JSON representation for the above schema is like this:-

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_courses_modules/51/",
    "name": "cdcsdc",
    "quiz": [{
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz/1/",
            "quiz_name": "Shash",
            "module_referred": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_courses_modules/19/"
    }]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is call the QuizSerializer's create method from within the Course_ModuleSerialzers Update method and then bind it to the Course_modules instance as a property.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the issue here? Is your update method not being invoked?

Comment: Your code can be written better python class names have no underscores  i.e `Course_ModuleSerializer` should be `CourseModuleSerializer`

Comment: Yes the update method gets invoked. I want to save the Quiz data through the Course_module serializers update method but not sure how to save it into the Quiz model through Quiz Serializer's create method And then finally bind it as a property to the Course_Module Object. If you have any idea please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

models.py

```
class CourseModule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    module_referred = models.ForeignKey(CourseModule, related_name="quiz_set")
```

serializer.py

```
class CourseModuleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    quiz = QuizSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = CourseModule
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'quiz')


    def create(self, validated_data):
        quiz_data = validated_data.pop('quiz', [])
        course_module = CourseModule.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if quiz_data:
            Quiz.objects.bulk_create(
              [
                 Quiz(module_referred=course_module, **quiz)
                 for quiz in quiz_data
              ],
            )
        return course_module

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)

        quiz_data = validated_data.get('quiz')
        if quiz_data:
            instance.quiz_set.clear()
            Quiz.objects.bulk_create(
               [
                 Quiz(module_referred=instance, **quiz)
                 for quiz in quiz_data
               ],
            )
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: How do I attach quiz_data to the instance and save?

Comment: Using the foreign key `related name` as a reverse reference to the related objects which you access using the  `.quiz_set` that is `model_name_set` you don't need to attach anything to the instance since its a one to many relationship. Using `instance.quiz_set.all()` should show all quiz data of the current instance.

Comment: I followed the same way BUt my response doesn't get's updated after the PUT/PATCH requests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741831/api-response-is-showing-outdated-data-with-put-patch-requests